# File upload to servlet optimizations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have a Spring-based web application that sometimes needs to send and receive potentially large documents as multi-part files. When files are uploaded, they are generally written straight to the data base. When downloaded, are always read and sent with out any processing. When load testing at some point the application starts throwing OutOfMemoryErrors. To address this issue, instead of loading a complete multi-part file into memory, I read and write straight between request/response in/out streams and the blob in the db. As expected, that fixed the OutOfMemoryErrors. However, then the application performs 3-7 times slower under low loads.

I would think that in order to load the whole multi-part file into memory and inject into a controller, it still needs to be read through the same request's input stream and underlying socket. How can Spring load the same files sent by same client that much faster then reading them directly?

edit: emphasis is on low loads. Once its been running for long enough or at high enough load performance would further deteriorate because (Im guessing) gc has to run pretty much constantly. What about before then?

adding relevant code:
basically this type controllers

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> saveStuff(..., MultipartFile file){
    .... 
    dao.save(..., file.getBytes());
 }
```

were replaced with

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> saveStuff(..., HttpServletRequest request){
    .... 
    dao.save(..., request.getInputStream());
 }
```

and in the dao the part that writes the input stream to the blob is

```
try {
    byte[] bytesRead = new byte[4096];
    while (in.read(bytesRead, 0, bytesRead.length) != -1) {
        toBlob.write(bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        toBlob.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code. The main issue would be the read buffer size. Reading the entire upload into memory first adds latency as well as wasting space, so it shouldn't be any faster than a properly written loop using a reasonable buffer size.

Comment: sure. added relevant code.

Comment: Have you disabled multipart parsing i.e. removed the `MultipartResolver`? Also https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html explains how to do streaming file uploads with the commons-fileupload. The `InputStream` in your case isn't the same as the `MultipartFile` so not sure if you are really writing the correct stuff to the database... Also wondering what is the `toBlob` stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't even correct, so why you're worrying about its performance isn't clear. Try this:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Unlike yours, this version writes the final partial buffer correctly.

As regards performance, I would experiment with an even larger buffer size, 32k or more.

Comment: oh my... youre right. thats tunnel vision. probably would not have realized until integration testing otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

So basically this whole question is overthinking a simple problem. And its really not about reading the request's input, but writing it to the data base that is slow. Basically instead of messing with buffers and reading/writing bytes all that needs to happen is

```
statement.setBinaryStream(paramIndex, requestInputStream, contentLength);
//....execute statement and stuff....
```